# New Ubuntu install defaults to try or install

Tags: system-installation

Hi I have just completed a new install of Ubuntu on an older i5 Acer PC. The install went fine but when I boot up I still see the Grub screen followed by the prompts asking me if I want to try or install Ubuntu etc. If I boot into it I see an icon for install Ubuntu and closing down prompts me to remove the installation media which I have already done.

Is there a way to fix this so it's just a regular install?

Comment: please [edit] your question with the version of ubuntu you installed and which installation media you used.

Comment: To be clear you have removed the Live Media what ever it was,  be it USB or DVD and rebooted? It does say Grub and a version number at the top of the screen on reboot?

Comment: Have you removed your installer CD/USB after installing? Open Disks and it will tell you which disk you have booted. What method did you use to install Ubuntu?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the questions but I just figured what I did wrong. I installed from DVD but didn't realise that I had installed to a USB plugged into the back, so it was booting from USB. I have now installed from the USB and it's all working fine.

Thanks everyone for jumping in to clarify.